# Как запрограммировть копирование ряда ячеек с сортировкой?

Tags: excel

Есть ряд ячеек с числами (вычислинными по формулам в этих ячейках).
Необходимо скопировать ряд значений этих ячеек в другой и отсортировать его по убыванию.  Также необходимо, чтобы это все обновлялось (изменились значения в исходном ряду - изменились также и в новом; и сортировка произошла автоматом).
Можно ли такое запрограммировать в excel? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*paulgri*, о макросах - неверно. Код может срабатывать по событиям.
Для этого код размещается в модуле листа.

Например, отслеживание изменений диапазона *A2:A10*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A2:A10"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    .....*здесь_что-то_выполняем*.....
    End If
End Sub
```

Отслеживание двойного клика:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
```

*Worksheet_BeforeRightClick* следит за правым кликом и т.д.

---

Реализация задачи формулой:

```
=НАИБОЛЬШИЙ($A$1:$A$10;СТРОКА(1:1))
```

где *$A$1:$A$10* - исходный диапазон.

При протягивании формулы по строкам будет изменяться индекс, заданный функцией *СТРОКА()*

Если результирующий диапазон нужен в строке, а не в столбце, индекс нужно находить другой функцией:

```
=НАИБОЛЬШИЙ($A$1:$A$10;СТОЛБЕЦ(A1))
```

Comment: @vikttur, по п.2 согласен - 3в1 ))

что касается событий листа: на изменение ячеек тоже? у меня к макросам недоверие на самом деле по другим причинам - поддерживаю некоторые доморощенные корпоративные решения, а у пользователей, особенно в MSO 10 и выше, по умолчанию уровень безопасности запрещает макросы, пока всем объяснишь...

Comment: О макросах - добавил в ответ.

Comment: @vikttur, спс ))

Answer (score 3):

Если действительно надо обновлять автоматически при изменении данных в исходном диапазоне, то все надо реализовать формулами (макросы не подойдут, их надо запускать). Попробуйте так:

1) в отдельном диапазоне найдите ранг каждого значения в исходной выборке;

2) в следующем диапазоне - исходный порядковый номер каждого значения, ранг которого совпадает с порядковым номером в этом диапазоне;

3) результат - используя предыдущее значение как индекс, извлеките значение из исходного диапазона.

```
значения: 28 13  9 47 34 22
ранг:      4  2  1  6  5  3   (позиция в отсортированном списке)
номер:     3  2  6  1  5  4   (позиция в исходном списке)
результат: 9 13 22 28 34 47
```

При некоторой сноровке можно совместить шаги 2 и 3 и избавиться от одного промежуточного диапазона.